# Getting array length in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

```
{
  "_id" : 654321,
  "first_name" : "John",
  "last_name" : "Doe",
  "interested_by" : [ "electronics", "sports", "music" ],
  "address" : {
    "name" : "John Doe",
    "company" : "Resultri",
    "street" : "1015 Mapple Street",
    "city" : "San Francisco",
    "state" : "CA",
    "zip_code" : 94105
  }
}
```

How can i find the name of elements in array 'intersted_by' using command??

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Do you want the number of elements in the "interested_by" array or the value of that field?

Comment: I was asking for the value of that field

Answer (score 1):

You can have the size of your result in the mongo shell using :

```
db.collection.count()
```

Replace collection by the name of your collection. You can also add a find condition like this :

```
db.collection.find().count()
```

Like that, you wan restrict your result with deffernts clauses before count the numbers of data corresponding

Edit : don't forget to do the command  `use databaseName`
        if you're not in your database, it does'nt work

Answer (score 0):

You can count the amount of keys by doing:

```
var count = Object.keys(myObject).length;
```

Comment: How do I get the name 'electronics','sports' and 'music' from 'intersted_by'